# How do i make a button activate JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

How do I make a html button activate javascript? 
For example, if I make a button and i click it, it activates a javascript code that confirms ("Hi"). Help would be appreciated!

And if you actually want me to give an example, I am new to this and this is what i have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<button type="button">This is the button</button>
<script language="javascript"> 
confirm("hi")
</script>
```

Comment: Massive amount of help here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event.

Comment: Yeah, StackOverflow works like this: "I want to achieve this, I've done that so far, but I am stuck at that point" and not "I want this, who will code this for me?"

Comment: Have you at least tried a [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+show+an+alert+on+click+of+a+button+using+javascript&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=30FqU5iLDpOEuATqvoDYBA)

Comment: this is such a difficult task, I bet no javascript tutorial has ever covered this.. :)

Comment: Now would be a great time to learn how to learn, rather than outsourcing your work to the internet.

Comment: yeah the google search didn't work

Comment: And no need to make me feel bad ):

Comment: No need of feeling bad,friend..Nobody is perfect..Try to learn and happy coding..

Comment: Wow Jay Harris thanks for the insightful help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search about events. In your case the `click` event to be specific. You have to handle the button's click event, like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="myButton" />
```

Then the script:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function()
{
    window.alert("Hi there!");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H4rH9/).

This is the simpler way of doing this. Here's some references for further information:

- [DOM Events @ Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events)
- [.onclick() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)
- [Using .addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)
- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348494/1267304)

Good luck.

Comment: @OP, the last link should be carefully read. It is often misunderstood what the difference is.

Comment: there happy put example.and thanks for help

Comment: @rlemon did you think isn't worth a read or as a reference?

Comment: @user3612541 sometimes people are a little rude on this forum, but get over it. Besides, try to read other's people questions to see how to ask on this forum properly.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I think you mis-understood. I urge the OP of the question to carefully read the last article (difference between on<event> and addeventlistener). I +1'd your answer.

Comment: @rlemon I see. I think you advised the OP because the content is a little advanced for him. If yes, you might be right, It didn't passed throgh my mind. Anyway thank you for your voting.

Comment: @user3612541 any problem with this ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown no no problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) to the button element (either via JS or as a tag attribute... for learning, I'd suggest the former), and use [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) to display the message.

I'm not going to give you the code because that's not what SO is about.